# passing choices by list

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using choices to save to database and when saved it appears ['option1', 'option2'] and I need only the correct name to appear.
and I need my model to continue as models.CharField

models.py

```
PETN_CHOICES = (
    ('Cachorro','Cachorro'), ('Gato','Gato'), ('Pássaros', 'Pássaros'), ('Peixes','Peixes'), ('Reptéis','Reptéis'), ('Roedores','Roedores')
)
class Negocio(models.Model):
   pet_aceitos = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PETN_CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
PETN_CHOICES = (
    ('Cachorro','Cachorro'), ('Gato','Gato'), ('Pássaros', 'Pássaros'), ('Peixes','Peixes'), ('Reptéis','Reptéis'), ('Roedores','Roedores')
)

class NegocioForm(UserCreationForm):
    pet_aceitos = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=PETN_CHOICES, )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between the form field you are using and the model field. In the `Negocio` model, pet_aceitos accepts only one value to be stored with the new instance, where in `NegocioForm` you are forcing a multiple choice field, meaning a list of values. What you want to do is maybe:

In `models.py`:

```
PETN_CHOICES = (
    ('Cachorro','Cachorro'), ('Gato','Gato'), ('Pássaros', 'Pássaros'), ('Peixes','Peixes'), ('Reptéis','Reptéis'), ('Roedores','Roedores')
)
class Negocio(models.Model):
   pet_aceitos = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=PETN_CHOICES)
```

In `views.py`:

```
class NegocioForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Negocio
        fields = ('pet_aceitos',)


class NegocioView(FormView):
    form_class = NegocioForm
    template_name = "yourtemplate.html"
    success_url = "success_redirect_url_name"
```

And in your `yourtemplate.html`:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
</form>
```